# Windows phone 7, code to indicate how many clicks of an image?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, network-programming

So I had a thought -- Say you have pictures streaming to your app from a webpage. Is there any way to put code in the app to find out how many times a person has tapped the image, or how many times they have pressed a button belonging to the image?

Think of the "Like" button for facebook, where people can have +1, and see the total count of how many people also "like" it.

If so, how would one go about coding this?

Answer (score 0):

You question is very vague...

If you want the count of how many time the image was loaded you can count that server side every time the picture is downloaded. If you want to give them a "like" button then you can add that to your WP7 app and call a page server side or a WCF service with some ID value for the picture to track the "likes".

For example:
HTTP Version

You can download the pictures from you webserver using a link such as "http://www.mysite.com/pictures.aspx?ID=Funnyfile.jpg&DeviceID=29393848293".

ID would be the unique ID for your application to know which picture to load
DeviceID would be the Device ID for the WP7 device loading the picture in your app (MSDN doesn't recommend you use the Device ID to identify unique users so you might need to adjust this value).

You could then set the [source of an Image Control to that URL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/37a5ce11-b3a1-42db-95d1-1a3c7e73c9a9/) to load the image.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mysite.com/pictures.aspx?ID=Funnyfile.jpg&DeviceID=29393848293", UriKind.Absolute);
   ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
   ProfileImage.Source = imgSource;
```

A WCF Service can use a similar manner and would allow you to pull a collection of images back from the server if you need to. The basics of building the service wouldn't be overly complicated, but I am omitting and example to save time.

Comment: Apologies for it being vague, but thank you for the really quick response. I would not be interested in how many times the image was loaded, but rather the latter of what you suggested -- how would I be able to call a page server side or establish a WCF service?

Comment: @Ryan you can view this video on how to do an HTTPWebRequest on Windows Phone 7. That will allow you to call a page server side and update your "like" information. http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/mtaulty/silverlight-using-httpwebrequest